# Given the following heteroscedastic linear model, why we can assum E(W) = 1 without loss of generality

Tags: generalized-linear-model, heteroscedasticity, weighted-regression

Consider a heteroscedastic linear model with data consisting of $n$ independent copies of $(Y,X,W)$, where $ Y\in \mathbb{R}^1, X \in \mathbb{R}^p, W >0$ is a weight with expectation one:
$$ Y = u + \beta^{T}X + \epsilon/ \sqrt{W}$$
where $\epsilon$ is independent of $(X, W)$ and $E(\epsilon)=0, Var(\epsilon) = \sigma^2$.

Question: why we can assume $E(W) = 1$ without loss of generality.

My first thought is: since this is a heteroscedastic model, we have to turn it into homoscedastic model. We can see $Var(Y|X, W) = \frac{\sigma^2}{W}$, so the next step is to multiple the original model by $\sqrt{W}$, and use weighted least square. But what confuses me is that why we talk about $"E(W)"$ here, does it have anything to do with the model assumption or the estimators?

Comment: The setting might be confusing, because this is basic arithmetic: simply adjust $\sigma$ to rescale $W.$

Comment: @ whuber yea, you are right, but the question asks me "why we can assum E(W) = 1", it confuses me a lot. lemme know what setting is confusing